# replacing a set of values of a data frame by another in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

Suppose I have a data frame(X) of dim 200 *100 where each element is anything between 1 and 20. I have another data frame(Y) where first column is 1:18 and second column is a set of characters (For example: a,d,a,c,b,b,d,c,...b,c,d ) {note that there are only four distinct characters a,b,c,d)

We need to replace each element of X by corresponding values in Y. It means the output should be a new data frame XX where each element is anything out of a,b,c,d,19,20.

Furthermore, Can we replace 19,20 by anything out of a,b,c,d by manipulation ?

Comment: Can you clarify the last line?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
x <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:20,200*100,TRUE),200,100))
y <- data.frame(1:20,c(sample(letters[1:4],18,TRUE),19,20))
apply(x,1,function(e) y[match(e,y[,1]),2])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the values directly

```
X[X < 19] <- as.character(Y[X[X < 19],2])
```

Note that you are converting the `X` columns to character.

As I understand "by manipulation", you can change the 19, 20 values with:

```
X[X == 19] <- 'c'
X[X == 20] <- 'a'
```